# BLE development on VIVO smartphones?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I face a problem when using a google ble demo on VIVO X7 and X9 android phones.
Here is the demo link: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt
The bluetoothadapter scans ble devices for 4 minutes and then stops automatically.
This problem only occurs on above 2 android phones. The ble scanning lasts longer on other android phone. There is no related info I can find on Google. Does anyone get the reason on that? Many thanks

Comment: Check the mobile bluetooth visibility timeout in settings.

Comment: there is no bluetooth visibility timeout setting in its system...

Answer (score -1):

i had same issue in vivo smartphone. Solution is, you can scan for 1 minute then stop scan for 1 second, then restart your scanning.